# How to find an orthogonal basis (in a complex vector-space sense) of a module over a polynomial ring?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, orthogonality

### Problem

After solving an eigenvalue problem symbolically I ran into an issue. For an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity three I found the following basis that spans the corresponding complex eigenspace

$$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}-(1-z_2^2)\\0\\z_2(1-z_3^2)\\1-z_3^2\\-z_3(1-z_2^2)\\0\end{pmatrix},\hspace{5ex}
v_2=\begin{pmatrix}z_3(1-z_1^2)\\-(1-z_3^2)\\0\\0\\1-z_1^2\\-z_1(1-z_3^2)\end{pmatrix},\hspace{5ex}
v_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\z_1(1-z_2^2)\\-(1-z_1^2)\\-z_2(1-z_1^2)\\0\\1-z_2^2\end{pmatrix}$$

where $z_1,z_2,z_3\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$.

Now, I want to find an orthogonal (not necessarily orthonormal) basis. The difficulty here is that it should only contain polynomials in the $z_i$ (negative powers are also allowed). Hence, the canonical approach using the Gram-Schmidt process doesn't work here. Additionally, the expressions for the orthogonal vectors should be as small as possible (sorry for my inability to phrase it more concisely).

### Status

First of all, I'm not studying Math so I struggle finding a strategy to solve this problem. After researching on the internet for a week I stumbled across the concept of modules over polynomial rings so I'm hoping that I'm using the correct terminology in my question.

To demonstrate my thought process I want to show that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthogonal:
$$v_1\cdot v_2^*=-(1-z_2^2)z_3^{-1}(1-z_1^{-2})-z_3(1-z_2^2)(1-z_1^{-2})\neq0$$
Note that due to the fact that the $z_i$ have unit magnitude their complex conjugate can be written as their inverse ($(z_i^n)^*=z_i^{-n}$).

As a next step I tried to build the orthogonal basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ from my original basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ using a linear combination of the latter
\begin{align*}
e_1 &= p_1 v_1 + q_1 v_2 + r_1 v_3\\
e_2 &= p_2 v_1 + q_2 v_2 + r_2 v_3\\
e_3 &= p_3 v_1 + q_3 v_2 + r_3 v_3
\end{align*}
where $p_i,q_i,r_i$ are polynomial in $z_1,z_2,z_3$ (also allowing negative exponents), e.g. $p_1=1+z_2^2-z_1^{-1}$.

Following this approach I tried different relationships between $p_i,q_i,r_i$ to utilize the symmetries in $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. All of my ideas ended up in rather lengthy equations that I couldn't solve.

Thanks in advance for any advice guiding me in the correct direction or proofing to me that such a basis does not exist! I'm happy to give more information about my problem!

Comment: You want to read about Gram-Schmidt Method but without the normalization.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! You are right, Gram Schmidt actually is an option!

Answer (score 1):

The Gram-Scmidt procedure reursively takes a set of linearly inedpendent vectors $$\{v_1,  ...,v_k,v_{k+1} \}$$ of which the first $k$ vectors have been constructed to be orthogonal and defines $$v_{k+1}'=v_{k+1}-\frac{v_{k+1}\bullet v_1}{v_1 \bullet v_1}v_1-...-\frac{v_{k+1}\bullet v_k}{v_k \bullet v_k}v_k$$,which produces an orthogonal  set$$\{v_1,  ...,v_k,v_{k+1}' \}$$ Modify the formula for $v_{k+1}'$ by multipling the right side by the product of all the $v_i \bullet v_i$ for $1 \le i \le k$. You will still have an orthogonal set of vectors but there won't be any undefined division.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! This is definitely a valid approach! My only concern is that the vectors will successively grow in size due to the multiplication by the denominators... Is there maybe a way to mitigate that issue by starting with a "smart" choice of $v_1$? Moreover, my next task would be to find a *orthonormal* basis that is of the form described in my question. Is that at all possible? If not, it would be also fine...